# Functional analysis, Kreyszig, Finite Set Definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book Introductory Analysis with applications by Kreyszig the following definition of a finite set is given:

> A set $M$ is said to be countable if $M$ is finite (has finitely many
>   elements) or if we can associate positive integers with the elements of
>   $M$ so that to each element of $M$ there corresponds a unique positive
>   integer and, conversely, to each positive integer $1, 2, 3,\ldots$ there
>   corresponds a unique element of $M$.

So if *"to each positive integer $1, 2, 3,\ldots$ there
corresponds a unique element of $M$"* then the set would be infinite because the no. of Integers is infinite isn't it?

Thank you so much

Siju

Comment: Thank you so much :-)

Comment: I guess I will post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definition begins with "A set $M$ is said to be *countable*", and therefore is not a definition of the word *finite*, but rather of the word *countable*. Every finite set is countable, but the converse does not hold, because, as you have observed, $\mathbb{N}$ is countable but not finite.